# Media Query Not IPhone

Tags: css, media-queries

I asked a similar question yesterday, but this one is now more precise to what I need.  I have the following media query

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 414px)
and (max-device-width : 736px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 3){

}
```

So that media query is for iphone 6 +.  I am not trying to do a media query for anything which is not an IPhone 6 +, so I am trying to inverse the above (I have to do it like this - to long to explain).  So I am trying

```
@media not screen
and (min-device-width : 414px)
and (max-device-width : 736px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 3){

}
```

But it does not seem to work.  Is there any reason for this?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure of what you're trying to accomplish but there's nothing specific to Apple products in your code. Webkit is a rendering engine used by many browsers in many platforms.

Comment: I need a media query for IPhone6 +, and then I need to opposite to this to target anything not an IPhone 6 +

Comment: But I'm sure your first query will match other browsers as well. Whatever, I'm not a media query guru but aren't you missing parenthesis?